# Provided the payslips and other offer letter but instead got rejected!

Tags: job-offer, human-resources

I recently cracked one position for the senior quality engineer for one company on 19th jan. In the HR round, i told them about the other offer letter I have with xyz company. The HR asked my expected CTC and I conveyed the same. After that on 23rd Jan, the HR asked for my payslips and current CTC and I provided the same meaning to get a offer letter. After that they asked the salary breakup for the offer letter with the xyz company which i again provided because I wanted to work with this new organization hoping that they will now provide me a letter. Now on mon 28 Jan, the HR called told me that they cannot provide that much figure and on mail they simply rejected me while attaining all my slips and other salary breakup which seems to me quite unprofessional. I called her stating  that they can negotiate on the figure and they simply should not have rejected me on terms of money. What should i do now? shall I follow up with them on mail or rather draft a mail for their unprofessional way?

Comment: The figure they were wanting maybe ridiculously lower than the one you're getting now. Companies are likely to delete all information they had on an unsuccessful candidate on first ability to

Comment: What is CTC? Please explain.

Comment: Hi Sanchi - can you provide some clarity on the actual issue? Are you upset that the company has kept the physical copies of the documents you provided? Or are you asking more about the negotiation process? Some of the answers below are addressing the company keeping the documents, but it's not clear to me if that's what bothered you, or if you were more bothered that they asked for them in the first place (and you don't care that they kept them).

Comment: You may have violated confidentiality with your current employer and company xyz by sending payslips and offer letter to  a 3rd party. This could get you in trouble if they find out, so you may want to fix this.

Comment: @Scaahu- I did not provided them the original pay slips, just the soft copies in general

Comment: @dwizum- Never in the first place i provided them the physical copies. Just the soft copies of the payslips were provided to them over the mail. I am kind of upset on the scene that i already told them about my current package which they now think is too high. Then in general practice they should have never ever have called me at first place for the interview.

Comment: "_while attaining all my slips and other salary breakup which seems to me quite unprofessional_", how do you want them to not attain your slips? Erase their memories?

Answer (score 11):

> I called her stating that they can negotiate on the figure and they
>   simply should not have rejected me on terms of money. What should i do
>   now? shall I follow up with them on mail or rather draft a mail for
>   their unprofessional way?

They rejected you. You asked for another chance. There's nothing more for you to do other than wait to see if they want to negotiate. That seems unlikely.

It's not clear what you consider unprofessional here. They decided that you are not worth whatever they feel they would need to pay you based on your payslips. That happens.

And even if it were unprofessional, there's nothing you can do about it at this point. Sending them a letter telling them that they behaved in an "uprofessional way" isn't going to get you a job.

You should probably either accept the offer from the company that gave you the offer letter, or continue looking for a job.

> while attaining all my slips and other salary breakup which seems to
>   me quite unprofessional.

If you meant to say *retaining*, rather than *attaining* here, and if you want your documents back, then just ask for them back. The company has no need for them any longer.

Answer (score 3):

***Edit**: Upon rereading, them keeping the original documents and not giving them back is unprofessional. But I stand by the rest of my answer.*

The short answer here is that they simply rejected your application during the application process. Unless you have signed a contract with them, you have no standing to claim any entitlement as to whether they employ you or not.

*Note: Offer letters might binding in some cultures. Where I'm from, an offer letter is meaningless when the employer decides to cancel the application process anyway. The contract is the only thing that counts.*

> I called her stating that they can negotiate on the figure and they simply should not have rejected me on terms of money.

Telling them they can negotiate the figure is fine. However, you don't get to decide what they *should* (and shouldn't) do.

If your prospective employer decides to dismiss your application, so be it. They are not required to hire you or go into negotiations with you simply because you went through the application procedure.

Telling your employer what they should do would (if I were the employer) be a surefire way to not get hired.

> they simply rejected me while attaining all my slips and other salary breakup which seems to me quite unprofessional.

You're free to consider this unprofessional. That's the nature of opinions: to each their own. If this means you don't want to apply for jobs with this company in the future, or e.g. buy their product, so be it. That's your decision.

> shall I follow up with them on mail

A courteous question can be fair enough unless you were already given a clear and definite answer. Though be warned that they may ignore your email if the case is already closed as far as they're concerned.

> or rather draft a mail for their unprofessional way?

That would be a way to get blacklisted from applying to this company in the future. I wouldn't hire you if you sent this to me. Additionally, I wouldn't hire you if I knew you sent this to a different prospective employer.

Comment: In fairness it is rude of the company to demand proof before rejecting the candidate. If they were unprepared to pay the requested wage then proof of previous wage is completely irrelevant.

Comment: I kind of agree with @P.Hopkinson here. I think it's wrong for the company to ask for the original of pay slips and attain them. Photo copy of the pay slips would be good enough for them. Retaining the original pay slips and then reject the OP is unprofessional to me.

Comment: @scaaahu: Retaining the original document is indeed unprofessional. That had slipped by me when I read the question.

Comment: But the **solution** is simply to return the original copies.  It has nothing to do with the actual job offer.  Even if they offered the job the request for originals was inappropriate.

Answer (score 0):

There may be two things going on here

1. You were out of their price range and they think either the gap is too big to negotiate or you are simply not worth this type of money to them. That happens and is perfectly normal
2. They used you to update their data base on the current market rates for offers, salaries and benefits.

You may have created a problem for yourself. Many companies consider payslips and offer letters confidential and would be quite unhappy if they found out you shared them with a different company. I would sent a written letter by registered mail:

1. Thank them for the interview and interest and that you hope it will work out in the future
2. You would like some of your documents back. Be specific about this: they can keep resume, cover letter or application form, but you want payslips and offer letter back.
3. These documents are considered confidential and the company is not allowed to share it with anyone
4. The company is not allowed to make and keep any copies

Comment: In the USA, I know payslips are required for certain applications like certain mortgage loans or applying for an apartment. I can't imagine a company would care if you gave it to someone, but the slip may contain PII information that is protected under the law and how companies may handle them.

Comment: As far as offer letters, I can't imagine companies would be upset if you shared it. However, they might get upset being used as a leverage to get a better offer from a different company. It's time they wasted in trying to get you on board when they could have went with a different person. So on that ground I agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

In over 30 years I have only given proof of pay one time.  In that instance I was offered a job but I rejected the offer due to the compensation package.  I was asked to show my current salary in order to justify a higher compensation than the organization expected.  They took the information and offered me a better package than the one I was already getting at my current job.
This one time was unique and I broke my usual rule of not disclosing my current salary, no matter what, because I trusted the intentions of the hiring manager.  That being said, I think it is best to understand what an organization considers the value of the role versus my value in the role.  A company that underpays because they can is not somewhere I want to work.  I believe that a company looking for what I am getting now is usually either, as one response has already noted, looking to use me for research or is trying to pay as little to me as possible rather than paying an established value for the role I would be fulfilling.  It is a rare exception for an organization to not understand the market value of any position.  The information is readily available.  Other than positions that are unusual, such as the one I referenced above, I see no positive reason for an organization to quiz me about current salary.  The job pays what it pays.  What I get now, or have gotten in the past, isn't relative.
An additional note:  Sometimes we get the opportunity to jump our salaries up by going to a new company.  If we disclose our pay rate every time we look for new opportunities we run the risk of only receiving incremental increases rather than realizing the benefits of higher pay based either upon improving our marketability or simply enjoying a role in a company willing to pay better than the one we are at.  A fork lift driver at company "A" certainly doesn't want an opportunity to manage the warehouse at company "B" to pay relative to current compensation.